# Can't enable multiple upload on the upload component of Prime NG

Tags: angular, primeng

I am trying to enable multiple uploads on the PrimeNG component for angular. And based on their documentation [Upload Component Documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/fileupload) I can see that we have to use a property "Multiple" to enable the multiple upload functionality. However, when I use the property given, I get an error below :

""

Below is my code :

```
<div class="card">
<p-fileUpload name="myfile[]" url="./upload.php" multiple="multiple"  accept=".zip, .fap">
</p-fileUpload>
```

I also tried setting the multiple variable to true in the component.ts file but it didn't work for me.

```
export class UploadComponent implements OnInit {

  multiple: boolean ;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.multiple = true;
  }

}
```

Can I know what is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you are not binding the property correctly.
To bind a property in a template. You need to use square brackets like this: `[multiple]="multiple"`

Without brackets, angular will not bind the property `multiple`; instead it will consider it as `'multiple'` string, and primeng will give you an error: `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.`

**Correct Code**

```html
<div class="card">
    <p-fileUpload name="myfile[]" url="./upload.php" [multiple]="multiple"  [auto]="true" accept=".zip, .fap">
    </p-fileUpload>
</div>
```

```js
export class UploadComponent implements OnInit {

  multiple: boolean ;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.multiple = true;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="card">
    <p-fileUpload name="myfile[]" url="./upload.php" [multiple]="true"  [auto]="true" accept=".zip, .fap">
    </p-fileUpload>
</div>
```

this should work `[multiple]="true"`